# module 'int' has no attribute 'from_bytes'

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I use: `help(int.from_bytes)` in a script, I get this error:
`AttributeError: module 'int' has no attribute 'from_bytes'`

But in the Python console it works:

```
from_bytes(bytes, byteorder, *, signed=False) method of builtins.type instance
        Return the integer represented by the given array of bytes.
```

If it can be useful, I've removed Python2 and I should have only Python3.

I must have missed something when searching the answer on the web because it seems quite basic.

Comment: Did you happen to name your script `int.py` and `import int` in your script somehow?

Comment: import int, yes

Comment: But the script is called main.py

Comment: I see. Then you probably have the [`int` module](https://pypi.org/project/int/) installed and imported it to override the built-in `int`. In short, don't `import int` unless you actually want to use that third-party module.

Answer (score 0):

I've removed

```
import int
```

from the script and it works now.

Thanks @blhsing